# Getting same Id for all dynamically generated buttons

Tags: jquery, .net, drop-down-menu

I created list of dynamic button according to DropDown items in Jquery, and assign them id and values as per dropdown items ,
I need to get id of buttons on button click .

I have tried this ..But this is not working ..

```
--- populating Dropdown and and creates button

                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                        $("#ddlLecturer").append($("<option></option>").val(value.LecturerId).html(value.LecturerName));
                        var r = '<input class="btns" type="button" id="'+value.LecturerId+'"+ value="' + value.LecturerName + '"/>';
                        $("#btn_list").append(r);
                    });
                },

                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

this is the HTML of button generated

```
<div id="btn_list"><input type="button" value="None" +="" id="1" class="btns"><input type="button" value="Prof1_4" +="" id="24" class="btns"></div>
```

2 buttons have id's 1 and 24

-----button's lick

```
 $(document).on('click', '.btns', function () {

                    var x = $('.btns').attr('id'); --this is not returning values

            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `$('.btns')` with clicked element  `$(this)`  try this:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.btns', function () {
      var x = $(this).attr('id'); 
});
```

Comment: @user3734952 no this will return clicked element id check if you are not setting same id to elements

Comment: no , still same result , I have updated the html of butons

Comment: yes , it is now starting to work after browser restart ... i have tried this code previously .. thanks anyway

Comment: I am getting only "undefined"

Comment: @MohitArora Finally i use function call inline in button tag like this <input class="" onclick = "read(this.id)" type="button" id="'+result[0]+'" value="submit">